# Possible to store some settings per launch (but reset between launches) using QSettings or other classes?

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

I have a Qt application where I'm already using `QSettings` to store persistent state between launches. However, there are some state-like things that I would like to store only as long as the current session is valid, and I would not like them to persist between different launches of the application.

Is there an option of `QSettings` that I'm missing -- or perhaps some other Qt-based solution to this? Or am I basically stuck rolling my own? (In the form of a static `std::hash_map` or something, I imagine.)

Comment: Why don't you store that information in memory?

Comment: @vahancho Essentially, I DO want to store it in memory. I'm just already using the `QSettings` paradigm, and using the same paradigm for storing settings both retained and volatile might improve readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option can be to use a temporary file ([`QTemporaryFile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtemporaryfile.html) is a convenient way to do it) to store the session settings, so it is automatically destroyed when you close de application (or the session, just closing both settings and temporary file):

```
QTemporaryFile tmpFile;
tmpFile.open();
QSettings sessionSettings(tmpFile.fileName(), QSettings::IniFormat);
```

Just store both the temporary file and the settings together so they have the same life-span.

Two comments on it: be aware that `QTemporaryFile::fileName()` returns an empty string until `open` is called. Also, you will have to use a file-based settings' format like INI or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Why using QSettings then? instead you are looking into a normal shared (singleton?) hashmap?

Quoting https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#details :

> If all you need is a non-persistent memory-based structure, consider
>   using QMap instead.